how to chroot sftp-server in wrapper script
I am already using a wrapper script for restricting ssh users to only some commands. Escpacially to borg serve for backup purpose.
Now I wanted to add to possibility to also use sftp in a chrooted folder. Like I already read on stackoverflow, I can not use the Subsystem sftp internal-sftp directive in sshd config because the internal-sftp command is not recognized outside of sshd (in the wrapper script).
Therefore I tried to use the other subsystem /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server and added this as a case in my wrapper script like this:
case "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" in
    "/usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server")
        /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server -d / -l VERBOSE

That worked instantly without any error. But the chroot is missing. Therfore I prepared a chroot folder with the needed permissions and mounts to /etc, /bin, /lib, /lib64 and /usr.
That did not work. Before I maybe messed up sth. with the chroot env I don't know, I decided to test this with chrooting into /.
Executing this manually throws no error but gives no output aswell:
/usr/sbin/chroot / /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server -d / -l VERBOSE
I also switched the line in the wrapper script to /usr/sbin/chroot / /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server -d / -l VERBOSE but the sftp connection does not work.
On the client side I get instantly
Connection closed
Connection closed.

and no additional logs.
I don't know what to try next to get this working...
